# ASIHTTPRequest simple post fail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, post, asihttprequest

I'm new in objective-c, and I'm now trying to write a simple user-sign-in program on iPhone. My idea is to use classes in ASIHTTPrequest to post information to a php file in localhost which is linked to a db. I set up a button, and if you press it, it send out the post request. However, nothing is inserted to db.
Here's my code:

.h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
-(IBAction)post;
```

.m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)post {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"localhost:8888/index.php"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:@"paul" forKey:@"user"];
    [request setPostValue:@"12345" forKey:@"pw"];
}
```

index.php file:

```
<?php
include('database.php');
session_start();
$link = connect_mysql();
mysql_select_db("test",$link);

if (($_POST["user"]=="")||($_POST["pw"]=="")) { header('Location:error.html'); exit(); }
      $sql = 'select * from userinfor where name="'.$_POST["user"].'";';
      $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
      $pass= mysql_fetch_object($result);
      if ($pass) { header('Location:again.html'); exit();}
      if ($_POST["pw"]!=$_POST["pw2"]) { header('Location:error2.html'); exit();}
      $sql = 'INSERT INTO userinfor (name, password) values ("'.$_POST["user"].'","'.$_POST["pw"].'")';
      $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);
      if (!$result) {
        echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
        echo 'MySQL Error: '. mysql_error();
        exit();
      } else {
        echo 'Sucessfully added entry<br/>';
        echo '<a href="login.html">Click to login</a>';
      }
?>
```

database.php file:

```
<?php
function connect_mysql() {
  //Connect to database (Please specify the password field if you needed
    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '12345');
    if (!$link) {
      die('Could not connect to mysql');
    }

    $db = mysql_select_db('test', $link);
    if (!$db) {
      die('Could not select database');
    }

   return $link;

}

?>
```

Comment: What "doesn't work"? Error messages?

Comment: first try to use **http://**, then ASIHTTP is not supported anymore, try AFNetworking instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you did not say to your request to start the request. Add

```
[request startAsynchronous];
```

or

```
[request startSynchronous];
```

Also, since you have to become the delegate of request be sure to add methods (become delegate by: `[request setDelegate:self];`):

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
```